# Why is my localStorage checkbox/boolean value comparison not working for my Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I have successfully mapped a boolean variable to my localstorage variables which is triggered by a checkbox on my options.html page for my Chrome extension.

What I want know is what the best way to show/hide an element based on whether that checkbox is checked in options on my popup.html (browser button event.) The following jQuery $("#myElement").hide(); does not work - nor would I expect it to... but I'm sort of at a loss as the best way to control displaying those elements to the end user.

Note: display: none for CSS is an option too - I just don't know the best way to go about this.

```
   var value = localStorage["myCheckbox"];
   alert(localStorage.getItem('store.settings.myCheckbox'));

   if (value != null)
        alert(value);//this works (true if checked, false if not checked...)

    if (!value){
        alert('hide the element'); 
        $("#myElement").hide(); //hide a div element in my popup (chrome extension button popup)
    }
```

Comment: You need to learn how to debug the popup.. Right-click your extension's button and choose "Inspect popup". You will see meaningful errors.

Comment: **Do not "edit away" the question.** Your question should keep the original problem, so that the answers present make sense. If you have a different question (that you call "part 2") - ask a separate question. I am rolling this back again, for the last time. Please keep this to the SO accepted format.

Comment: The reason why the question should be kept is the goal of Stack Overflow - it's not about helping you specifically, but helping everyone with the same problem. As such, the problem must remain. You can add to your question (though a question should ideally not be multi-part, split them), but answers already present must still make sense.

Comment: Sorry I see the value in doing it this way. It makes sense. I'll ask a new question. Could we change the name of this question at least - it has nothing to do with showing/hiding elements and how to call that via javascript or jquery. (Part 2 was never addressed, which is really what the title describes, IMHO.) I'll want to keep this old title in my new question but I don't want change it without your consent.

Comment: Please do! That will improve the question. I'll be sure to upvote after your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are assigning the `.checked` property of your checkbox to `localStorage["myCheckbox"]`, so, since that **`localStorage` variables can only be strings**, it can be either `"true"` or `"false"`, depending on the checkbox's state.

Your error is doing this:

```
if (!value) { 
    ...
}
```

**the above condition will never be satisfied**, because a non-empty string (such as "true" or "false") is always `true` in JavaScript, so `!"string"` is always false. Hence, to check the value of your checkbox in your `popup.js` you should do:

```
var isChecked = localStorage.myCheckbox === "true";

if (!isChecked) $('#myElement').hide();
// if the checkbox is not checked hide the element
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright I fixed the first issue - (it was returning strings so I needed to use ===)

However I still need to figure out the best way to do part 2 - the show/hide functionality. I will post a new question and update this with the link. Thanks so much for your help, Marco!

```
   var value = localStorage["myCheckbox"];
   var isChecked = localStorage.getItem('store.settings.myCheckbox');

    if (isChecked === "false"){ 
    alert('its FALSE');
    $('#myElement').hide();
    }

    if (isChecked === "true"){
    alert('its TRUE');
    $('#myElement').show();
    }
```